# How to change the password input from letters to ****

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords

I am using a very simple php form to password protect one page. I would like the character '*' to appear in the box when they are typing in

```
           <form name="form1" method="post" action="checkpw.php">
    <table><tr><td colspan="2">
    <p class="form"> Password: <span id="formfield"><input name="pw" type="text" id="pw"></span></p></td>
    <tr><td valign="top"></td><td align="right"><span class="submitbt"><input type="image" class="rollover" src="images/buttons/BTN_Submit.png" id="contact_submit" alt="Submit" width="72px" height="68px" border="0" hover="images/buttons/BTN_Submit_over.png" name="submitbt" value="Login"></span></td>
```

Comment: I recommend you a HTML manual like http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: @Lobo http://w3fools.com

Comment: The question has a simple answer, so I don’t see a reason why it was closed. A correct and useful answer was given.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't think these type of questions should be encouraged and reopened. It clearly shows no research effort at all. If I asked "which form element to use for a radio button" and then "which for element to use for a dropdown", they should be closed either.

Comment: Using a text input field for reading a password works rather well, and in some ways it is even better than using type=password. In that sense the question is rather natural; only when you wish to change the input to `****` does the need for type=password really arise. Admittedly, reading a good tutorial would have answered the question, but the same applies to many other legitimate questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<input name="pw" type="text" id="pw">
```

Use:

```
<input name="pw" type="password" id="pw">
```

See the types of `input` elements on the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1):

> password: Like "text", but the input text is rendered in such a way as to hide the characters (e.g., a series of asterisks). This control type is often used for sensitive input such as passwords. Note that the current value is the text entered by the user, not the text rendered by the user agent.

Comment: input tags should be selfclosing...

Comment: @meo - Only in XHTML. There is no need in HTML. See the examples in the linked spec.

Comment: i had some IE problems when i did not

Comment: Thanks this is my first login form - didn't realise that it was such an easy fix with the html.

Answer (score 2):

use `<input type="password" />`